# calling a function from another class file

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a class `LogisticRegression` in a file called `logisticRegression.py`.

In this class I create a function called `negative_log_likelihood(self,y)`.

In another script I introduce a new object of class `LogisticRegression` and it is working normaly.

But if I call the function `negative_log_likelihood` it doesn't work. It gives me:

> AttributeError: 'LogisticRegression' object has no attribute negative_log_likelihood'

I called the function using

```
from logisticRegression import negative_log_likelihood
```

But it doesnt work.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you need to import your class and then call the function with the instance of you class.

Like that:

```
from logisticRegression import LogisticRegression

my_instance = LogisticRegression()
my_instance.negative_log_likelihood()
```